# Would it be sexist for a beer shop to have a "selection of beer for women"?

Tags: specialty-beers, classification

I was on a webshop for beer and was surprised to find a "selection of beer for women". It consisted mostly of fruit-flavored beers and other sweet-type beverages such as ciders.

This struck me initially as sexist, since women can, and do, like all kinds of beer. I decided to ask the company and they said that those are the beers that their female customers order most (although I'm doubtful that they did a statistical analysis...).

I'm curious if beer experts out there believe there should be a category of "beer for women" and if so, what would be in that category.

Comment: I'm not necessarily a beer expert, but I agree with you that this is sexist. And stupid.

Comment: I don't know that I'd think it's pejorative enough to count as "sexist" to my mind, but it's probably not a great choice.  There are plenty of guys who like sweeter or fruitier beers too.  Probably it's wiser to characterize the products, not the customers.

Comment: All marketing. Don't like it, don't buy from them. I see things advertised based on gender and race.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I think this is a pretty unnecessary (and non-descriptive) label to put on a category of alcohol. If I go to a liquor store looking for cider or for a dry stout or for anything else and I see a section labeled "women" that effectively tells me absolutely nothing about what it is I'll find over there. Not to mention it basically assumes a woman will have no clue what it is she's looking for, so we'll just label this shelf "women".

I would definitely opt for something more descriptive and that doesn't imply clueless-ness i.e. "Radlers and Ciders", "IPAs", etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Why would you have a “selection of beer for women”?**

1. this is a marketing strategy that aims both women and men.
2. women like to be treated differently, as a consumer with special needs and expectations.
3. men looking for a gift to a woman will most likely be attracted by this selection.

---

From Bridget Brennan, a contributor to Forbes, and head of [Female Factor](http://www.thefemalefactor.com/services/marketing_consulting.html): *The often repeated phrase, “I know 50% of my marketing budget is wasted, I just don't know which 50%” – has an answer. It's the 50% that doesn't appeal to women.*

She stressed the importance of thinking holistically and practically when working to promote any product to women. Be it color, size, or smell, it's all intended to catch woman's attention.

> Women shop with all their senses.  Is your store a place that people want to linger?  How does it smell, how does it sound?  This creates an opportunity to reach the senses that e-commerce can't.  Women consumers in particular are highly attuned to the details of a retail environment, from scent to lighting to music to the tactile nature of touching and examining products.

From Tom Peters [the truth about marketing to women](http://www.marketingdonut.co.uk/marketing-strategy/your-target-market/the-truth-about-marketing-to-women):

> The times they are a-changing. So the situation is as follows:
>   Women are the number one business opportunity. They buy lots of stuff. Men and women are very different. Men are (still) in control and are totally, hopelessly, clueless about women. Not enough “stuff” is designed for women or communicated in a way that appeals to women. Most stuff for women is, to be frank, pretty patronising.
>
> This is a straight-down-the-line commercial argument. Women are not a niche market or a minority - they have wallets and, for many businesses, women as decision-makers and consumers hold the key to future success.

---

**Now, is it sexist?**

I can't say, but my 2 cents: *when targeting women, you're even more willing to add a* **pink tax**.

Read more about it here: [how gender based pricing hurts women's buying power](https://www.jec.senate.gov/public/_cache/files/8a42df04-8b6d-4949-b20b-6f40a326db9e/the-pink-tax---how-gender-based-pricing-hurts-women-s-buying-power.pdf)

Comment: Not been around for a while (months), but really, give me a break - my first reaction (as a woman) would be to run away, but then I would stand back and laugh.  Also if my husband gave me a bottle of sweet beer I would either have to kill him or divorce him - which ever is the simplest!  Haven't women got over this 'girl power' thing yet, I feel embarrassed to be female.

Comment: @dougal4.0.0 : I can't say you're wrong or even disagree, I just tried and give OP what could possibly be the tactical aspect of such a choice from a store. Unfortunately, many shops still think they can target women using the same old "nasty"(?) tricks... I believe its completely *wrong* ( just to remain polite) but it doesn't mean one shouldn't take that into account, don't you think?